# Ember send action from one component to other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a parent component my-section.hbs defined as below;

```
{{#my-scale}}
{{my-field}}
{{/my-scale}}
```

Now in my-field, I have

```
{{my-textfield label=fldName key-up="onFieldChange"}}
```

My question is how do I get access to onFieldChange in my-scale component?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem by having `my-scale` provide the action that `my-field` will invoke. You can do this through a [Closure Action](https://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-closure-actions/)

Since a "block" component (like `my-scale` can provide variables to its block (where `my-field` is) you can yield the action to call on `key-up`

```
// my-field.hbs
{{yield (action 'some-action-to-invoke-on-key-up')}}
```

and then pass it into the field

```
{{#my-scale as |someAction|}}
  {{my-field action=(action someAction)}}
{{/my-scale}}
```

which you can then bind to the `key-up` event

```
{{my-textfield label=fldName key-up=(action someAction)}}
```

This is IMO a bit easier than bubbling regular actions; you can pass the function around as a function instead, and just call it like a regular function (or bind it to an event)

I put together a little demo so you can see it in action [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/7d1e645ae48487e50dfbbdc00c3675be?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-scale.hbs).

Comment: I saw you defined functionName like `'update-value'(value)` this code in your twiddle. is it equivalent to `updateValue(value)`. Could you please point me to understand what is this ?

Comment: Having an action called `updateValue` or `update-value` is pretty much the same. My personal preference is just to kebab-case actions to make them stand out from values, but it is functionally equivalent.

The only thing that matters is that the string passed to the `action` helper matches the name of the action defined in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sendAction()` at each layer you want to bubble up.  So, in this case, you need to bubble up twice to go from `myTextfield` to `myField` to `myScale`.

```
// templates/my-section.hbs
  {{#my-scale}}
  {{my-field}}
  {{/my-scale}}

// component/myTextfield.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    onFieldChange() {
      this.sendAction('onFieldChange');
    }
  }
});

// component/myField.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    onFieldChange() {
      this.sendAction('onFieldChange');
    }
  }

// component/myScale.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    onFieldChange() {
      // do something
    }
  }
});
```

Alternatively, consider using something like [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) and specifying your actions on the route.